# Copy and files between two different S3 buckets in different accounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to copy one file from one S3 bucket in my account to a different S3 bucket in another account of which I have assumed the role for.

I am getting the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"
```

Here is my method and a description of each component:

1. Created a new role with * s3 access and assumes ARN of the role on the destination bucket
2. BucketA is the origin bucket and has one file in it: names.csv
3. BucketB is the destination bucket

Code:

```
#resources
bucketB_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id = aak,aws_secret_access_key=ask)
bucketB_s3 = bucketB_session.resource('s3')
#copy files
copy_source = {'Bucket': 'BucketA','Key': 'names.csv'}
bucketB_s3.Object("BucketB", 'names.csv').copy(copy_source)
```

Comment: This API call uses a single set of AWS credentials. Those credentials must have read access to the source account/bucket/object and write access to the destination account/bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is:

- **Account-A** with `Bucket-A`
- **Account-B** with `Bucket-B`
- You wish to copy files from `Bucket-A` to `Bucket-B`

An Amazon S3 copy operation requires a **single set of credentials** that has permission to Read from `Bucket-A` and write to `Bucket-B`.

This can be done in either by **pushing** the object, or **pulling** the object.

**Pushing from Account A to Account B**

This involves using credentials (an IAM User or and IAM Role) from the **Source account**. The IAM entity should be given permissions to:

- Read from `Bucket-A`
- Write to `Bucket-B`

Since this is a cross-account operation, a **Bucket Policy** is also required on `Bucket-B` that permits that IAM entity to write to `Bucket-B`:

```json
{
  "Id": "PolicyB",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GrantAccessToUserA",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-B/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A:user/USER-A"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Important:** If `Bucket-B` is configured with "ACLs enabled", be sure to specify `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` when copying the object. This means that the object will be owned by the owner of `Bucket-B`. If you don't do this, the object will still be owned by Account A and can't be deleted by Account B, even with admin rights! If `Bucket-B` is configured as **ACLs disabled** then this does not apply.

**Pulling from Bucket A using Account B**

This involves using credentials from the **Destination account**. The IAM entity in Account B should be given permission to:

- Read from `Bucket-A`
- Write to `Bucket-B`

Since this is a cross-account operation, a **Bucket Policy** is also required on `Bucket-A` that permits that IAM entity to read from `Bucket-A`:

```json
{
  "Id": "PolicyA",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GrantAccessToUserB",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject""
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-A/*"
      ],
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-B:user/USER-B"
    }
  ]
}
```